# apt-get upgrade and apt-get update are now broken for me in 10.04

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, updates, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

For some reason upgrade and update are now broken in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed line 5 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/akirad.list (dist parse)
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Malformed line 5 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/akirad.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Here is the file it says line 5 is screwed up in

```
## Akirad Repository for Ubuntu
## Please report any bug on akir4d at gmail.com

## ppa
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/akirad/ubuntu  main #Akirad Repository - Main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/ppa/ubuntu  main #Akirad Repository - Main

#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/akirad/ubuntu  main #Akirad Repository Sources- Main

#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/ppa/ubuntu  main #Akirad Repository Sources- Main
```

What is wrong with the link **deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/akirad/ubuntu main #Akirad Repository - Main** in line 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not use this repository. However your file is indeed wrong.

Comment your two deb lines and add this one (they will never work again so you are free to remove them afterwards) :

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/akirad/ubuntu lucid main

your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/akirad.list should look like this :

```
## Akirad Repository for Ubuntu
## Please report any bug on akir4d at gmail.com

## ppa
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/akirad/ubuntu lucid main #Akirad Repository - Main
#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/akirad/akirad/ubuntu lucid main #Akirad Repository Sources- Main
```

Note the addition of "lucid" to the line.

For more information look at the ppa launchpad page :

https://launchpad.net/~akirad/+archive/akirad?field.series_filter=lucid
and click on "Technical details about this PPA"

In case another ppa is making you trouble go directly to it's launchpad webpage for more info.

Best Regards.