# How do I fix "malformed line" errors in sources.list?

Tags: apt, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

I had problems with my movie player.  The sound was fine but the picture seemed to hesitate or stick or pause every few seconds so I was looking for some help on how to do this.

I tried to install a command in the terminal and got this message:

`E:Malformed line 68 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)`

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem. I cannot open the software center or the update manager.  The only other option I can think of is to wipe everything out and do a clean install. Thank you.