# Why is update manager giving me `malformed line' errors?

Tags: 11.10, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

I'm using Ubuntu now for almost one year, but I'm not too much of a programmer.
Lately I got problems with updating everything, the software manager refuses to search for updates and gives me responses like:

```
Could not initialize the package information

An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the update-manager package and include the following error message:

E:Malformed line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (absolute dist), E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Does anybody can help me? Just want to update to 12.04 and get it working again.
Thanks in advance

Patrick

Ok, this is what I get by entering `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` into the terminal:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)]/ oneiric main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main restricted
deb-src htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates main restricted
deb-src htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric universe
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric multiverse
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb htp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
deb-src htp://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb htp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src htp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb htp://archive.canonical.com / natty partner
deb-src htp://archive.canonical.com / natty partner
deb htp://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-proposed restricted main multiverse universe

Hope that helps.
```

---

Ok guys, I just deleted some lines in the above postet text by trial and error. it's working not again, but don't ask why it's working now again.
I'm happy it works, but could anybody explain to me, why?

I just deleted line: `deb-src htp://archive.canonical.com / natty partner`

Just want to at least try to understand a bit of my computer and what it does.

Comment: Try removing the line 52 from source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Could you attach the output of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

All your deb lines say **`htp://`!**

- It's `http`, and this little typo can cause errors.
- Fix it by running this in the terminal: `sudo sed -i -e 's/htp/http/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Your specific error was due to this malformed line:

```
deb htp://archive.canonical.com / natty partner
```

The correct repository URL is `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu`.