# I cannot use Software-Center or `apt-get update`

Tags: software-center, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

I can't open Ubuntu software-center. And I can't update in Terminal. When I type `sudo apt-get update`, it just shows:

```
E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

Comment: Please refer to this http://askubuntu.com/a/152300/63025, and post the asked content , by editing your question.

Comment: Forgot to add , **USE you Erroneous  Line Number in Third Step.**

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal and run `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker.list`
- Remove all the existing lines in the file, and add these lines

  `deb ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu oneiric main`
   `deb-src ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu oneiric main`.
- Exit gedit and then run `sudo apt-get update`. you will be file

Comment: I jus fixed it i needet to delete gnomebaker.list file and it forx 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
deb ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu o
```

The file's cut off. It should be like this;

```
deb ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu oneiric main deb-src
deb-src ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Comment: I CAN'T EDIT WHAT FILE;(

Comment: `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnomebaker.list`

Answer (score 0):

(Answer to your question what file to open, sorry can't comment)

Open 'software sources' and in the tab 'Other software', select the gnomebaker respository, then 'edit' and change according to RobinJ's answer. Then run 'sudo apt-get update' and try installing again...

Hope it works

Comment: How to open software sources im new on ubuntu:/

Comment: What do you have? 10.04? 11.10? 12.04?

Comment: I have ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hm, I just realized it's probably not installed by default in 12.04... Could you check? In launcher-dash, type 'software sources', does the app start?

Comment: How to i need to check it im new in ubuntu and i don't understand;(

Comment: The launcher is the panel on the left with the big icons, the dash is the top icon, where you type in the name of the application you want to start. What happens when you type in 'software sources'? Is the app there and can you start it by entering? If not, I'm afraid I can't help you, you would have to install it, and since you can't run software center, that would be a problem... Then you would have to try to run in terminal what RobinJ suggests, save the file and try running software-center again. You know what a terminal is?

Comment: Yes i know what is Terminal

Comment: OH Dash i know what is dash :D

Comment: I don't have software sources :(

Comment: Open terminal and type "gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list". Now the file 'sources.list' is opened in gedit. In this file, look for the line with 'deb ppa launchpad.net/gnomebaker... and the line with deb-src ppa.launchpad.net etc... and change both according to RobinJ's suggestion. Save the file and try software center again.

Comment: I'm sorry, if that doesn't work, try exactly what RobinJ proposes, I just figured out the ppa is indeed a seperate file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. It should work (I'm sorry, I always do this using Software Sources, so it's also hard for me... :-(

Comment: There is no line with what code;(

Comment: ... that code(?) Try exactly what RobinJ suggests (sorry for the confusion), then save and try software centre again