# how can i solve this problem in error during update?

Tags: apt, update-manager, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

I received this error message during an update and I do not know how to solve?

```
could not initialize the package information  
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the 
following error message:  'E:Malformed line 59 in source list 
/etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'
```

Comment: It means when you were editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` you made a typo, please edit your question and add the contents of that file.

Comment: root@drtamer-G41MT-S2PT:/home/marwa# sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.lis      >>>>>>the then gedit open with alot deb.#  but the line were 49 only

Comment: @marwa Please **edit this question** and include **all the text from the file** in it. Even if it doesn't contain the correct number of lines.

Comment: dear Eliah Kagan i try to make edit on my Q. but  i received massage Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.so what can i do ???

Comment: @marwa After you edit the question, select the file content that you just pasted and press Ctrl-K. That will make the content look like a code and will let you submit the edit.