# Update Manager Crashed

Tags: upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

When I tried to update Ubuntu with the terminal i get the following error:

```
E: Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read...
```

What does this mean? And how can I resolve this?

Lucio: ON the terminal I write sudo apt-get update

Web-E: after running cat /etc/apt/sources.list

I get all the data of the sources.list...
the last ltwo ines (59 and 60)  says like this

> deb http://arechive.canonical.com/ precisepartner
>
> deb-src http://arechive.canonical.com/ precisepartner

Comment: What is the exactly command that are you entering? Edit your question and add it.

Comment: Please run the following in terminal `cat /etc/apt/source.list` and edit your question with the output. You can open the file in gedit and  into look line 59. The file is located under `/etc/apt/source.list` directory

Answer (score 0):

Change `arechive` to `archive` and also change `precisepartner` to `precise partner` on lines 59 and 60 of `/etc/apt/sources.list` .