# E: Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse) E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: 12.04, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

The software center wasn't working so I tried to uninstall and and reinstall and I got this message:

```
E: Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

These are lines 59 and 60:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
```