# Ubuntu Software Source File Error

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

Whenever I try to install any software using terminal or by entering `sudo apt-get update`, the result is:

```
E: Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

My sources.list is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1180079/ .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like lines 56 and 57 of your file are trying to set your home directory as a package source.

If you don't want this, you can just edit the file and delete these lines.

If you do want this, you will need to change `deb file:///home/pradnesh main` to `deb file:///home/pradnesh precise main` in line 56 and a similar change in line 57.